# In how many different ways can the letters in the phrase "EMPIIRE" be ordered such that the first letter is a vowel?

Tags: combinatorics

In how many different ways can the letters in the phrase "EMPIIRE" be ordered such that the first letter is a vowel?

$4\cdot 6!/(2\cdot 2)$ is my answer.

$I_1MPRE_1E_2I_2$

$I_1MPRE_2E_1I_2$

I am not sure whether dividing by $2^2$ cancels out the duplicated ways.

Comment: Don't use `x` for multiplication in math mode (arguably, ever). Use `\cdot` *a la* $2\cdot 3$ vs $2x3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two methods:

Method 1: 
Either the first letter is an E, or an I.  
So, assume that it is an I, an attach a factor of $(2)$, because by symmetry, since there are the same number of E's as I's, the computation should be the same in each case.

Under the assumption that the first letter is an I, the computation is then

$$\frac{6!}{2!}. \tag1 $$

In (1) above, the numerator reflects that there are $6$ remaining letters to permute.  The denominator reflects that if the E's are designated as E-1, E_2, they can occur in any order.

Therefore, the final computation is

$$2 \times \frac{6!}{2!} = 6!.$$

---

Method 2:
Ignoring the start-with-vowel-constraint, the enumeration is

$$\frac{7!}{(2!)\times (2!)}. \tag2 $$

In (2) above, the denominator is explained by reasoning that E-1 and E-2 can occur in any order, as can I-1, I-2.

To adjust the computation in (2), you can reason that the **probability** that a random permutation of the $(7)$ letters starts with a vowel is $~\displaystyle \frac{4}{7}.$

Therefore, the desired computation must be

$$ \frac{4}{7} \times \frac{7!}{(2!)\times (2!)}, $$

which agrees with the computation from Method 1.

Answer (score 1):

The first letter must be an E or I. For the following $6$ letters, we are rearranging "MPIIRE" or "EMPIRE". There are $6!/2!$ ways to rearrange "MPIIRE" and $6!/2!$ ways to rearrange "EMPIRE". So, there are
$$\frac{6!}{2!}+\frac{6!}{2!}=6!$$
ways to rearrange "EMPIIRE" such that the first letter is a vowel.

Answer (score 0):

Choose the starting vowel in $2$ ways and permute the rest, which has a vowel repeated

thus $\;2\times\dfrac{6!}{2!} = 6!$